# the "code" function isn't working on Git Bash (windows)

Tags: visual-studio-code, path, git-bash

I recently factory reset my computer, after installing git bash I noticed that the "code" function og VS CODE wasnt working, it was returning an error:

bash: code: command not found

and so i went online and tried to look fot a solution, all i could find was adding it to PATH. well i checked and its there (echo $PATH):

/c/Users/tomas/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/mingw64/bin:/usr/bin:/c/Users/tomas/bin:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Python39/Scripts:/c/Python39:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH:/c/Program Files/nodejs:/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/c/Users/tomas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38/Scripts:/c/Users/tomas/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38:/c/Users/tomas/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/cmd:/c/Users/tomas/AppData/Roaming/npm:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin

(maybe this is just me not understanding how git bash $PATH syntax works but i checked it through enviroment variables and the path was there)

i also reinstalled vs code and git bash and still no luck, thx fot the help in advance

Comment: It's unlikely `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin` is the correct path for `code`. The path probably starts with `/c/`. Before messing around with git bash, I suggest you get it to work in PowerShell or CMD first.

Comment: it does work on both, only git bash is the problem, could you provide a way to change this path in git bash?